# Is the measurement for system characterization an "abstract idea"?

Tags: intellectual-property, patents, claims

[Patent #6,128,415](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6128415A/en) claims were reversed based on 'the claim is directed to an abstract idea'    [Example 5. Digital Image Processing (pp 13)](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/abstract_idea_examples.pdf) provides a **ineligible** patent claim:

> A method of generating a device profile that describes properties of a
>   device in a digital image reproduction system for capturing,
>   transforming or rendering an image, said method comprising:
>
> - generating first data for describing a device dependent transformation of color information content of the image to a device
>     independent color space through use of measured chromatic stimuli and
>     device response characteristic functions;
> - generating second data for describing a device dependent transformation of spatial information content of the image in said
>     device independent color space through use of spatial stimuli and
>     device response characteristic functions; and
> - combining said first and second data into the device profile.

As engineer, I am struggling to understand the notion of 'the claim is directed to an abstract idea'.  Engineers model and characterize systems (in the example: system characterization is labeled 'device profile') with mathematics, so it is important to understand the notion from a 101 patentability standpoint.  Because modern engineering is dependent upon measurement and mathematical modeling, **I am concerned that any claim containing a mathematic operations creates a serious vulnerability in the future: be it with the examiner or in a court**

I was surprised that Analysis deemed the mathematical characterization of a system through defined and limited measurements would be deemed 'directed to an abstract idea'.  I suspect that my surprise is caused by my inability to answer the question:

- What is the thought process for constructing a litmus test (question) for an 'abstract idea'?

The example's image processing system is not stochastic and stationary.  On the other hand: a system-of-interest performs a periodic system characterization of stochastic and non-stationary systems ('moving targets'): forming a dependent claim.   The periodic system characterizations provides some of the high-fidelity inputs to a process, which produces high-value decision support.

Although the system-characterization claim is an improvement to the prior-art, it seems that it is relegated to a claims **ineligible** analysis:

> The claim recites a method of generating first data and second data
>   using mathematical techniques and combining the first and second data
>   into a device profile. In other words, **the claimed method simply
>   describes the concept of gathering and combining data by reciting
>   steps of organizing information through mathematical relationships**.
>   The gathering and combining merely employs mathematical relationships
>   to manipulate existing information to generate additional
>   information in the form of a ‘device profile,’ ***without limit to
>   any use of the device profile.*** This idea is similar to the basic
>   concept of manipulating information using mathematical relationships
>   (e.g., converting numerical representation in Benson), which has been
>   found by the courts to be an abstract idea. Therefore, the claim is
>   directed to an abstract idea (Step 2A: YES).

- Is there any mode where system characterization is not 'directed to an abstract idea'?
- What does 'without limit to any use of the device profile' mean?

How would one author a system-characterization dependent claim  a ['building block'? as described by the court in ***Alice***:](https://patentlyo.com/patent/2014/07/structure-patent-ineligible.html)

> Accordingly, in applying the §101 exception, we must distinguish
>   between patents that claim the “‘buildin[g] block[s]'” of human
>   ingenuity and those that integrate the building blocks into something
>   more, Mayo, 566 U. S., at **_ (slip op., at 20), thereby
>   “transform[ing]” them into a patent-eligible invention, id., at _**
>   (slip op., at 3). The former “would risk disproportionately tying up
>   the use of the underlying” ideas, id., at ___ (slip op., at 4), and
>   are therefore ineligible for patent protection. The latter pose no
>   comparable risk of pre-emption, and therefore remain eligible for the
>   monopoly granted under our patent laws.

- If a claim comprises the use of mathematics: is it always labeled a 'judicially recognized exception' as shown in the diagram:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If mathematical equations are not patentable, why are algorithms patentable?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28236/if-mathematical-equations-are-not-patentable-why-are-algorithms-patentable)

Comment: See also https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-much-more-needs-to-be-added-to-an-abstract-idea-in-order-to-pass-the-subje?rq=1

Comment: Also https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15807/abstract-idea-definition?rq=1

Comment: Also by same stack exchange member https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28743/patent-claims-software-vs-machine-taxonomy-classification?rq=1